# Count columns in Excel that contain a value or text

Tags: excel, count, multiple-columns

I've done a survey.The questions are likert scale 1-10 plus don't know option.
I'm trying to count the number of columns that have some content, for example a value.
Assume I have 30 columns, but due to conditional logical not all respondents will answer all 30 questions/columns.
I want to count the number of questions/columns for every individual and store it in my file.

```
ID--------No.of questions
100--------30
101--------27
102--------14
```

Comment: Try `counta()`? I think they all work column wise.